# Infer Types from Tagged Template Literal Function argment

Tags: typescript

I want get Types from Generic Argment in tagged template literal function.

but typescript cant read from argment 'template'. It just read type as TemplateStringsArray.

```js
const tag = <T extends ReadonlyArray<string>>(template: T, ...args: string[]) => {
  return {template, args};
};

const a = tag`hello ${'world'}`;
/**

const a: {
    template: TemplateStringsArray;
    args: string[];
}
*/
```

Is there any way to understand `template` as `['hello ', '']`?

Comment: Can you clarify what ```value``` is in your question?

Comment: Interesting question. I have never use template literals in this way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem here is that `TemplateStringsArray` is not parameterized. See [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33304).

But you can still infer all but first argument of template literal function:

```js
const tag = <
    Elem extends string,
    Template extends ReadonlyArray<Elem>,
    Arg extends string,
    Args extends Arg[]
>(template: Template, ...args: [...Args]) => ({ template, args })

// const a: {
//     template: TemplateStringsArray;
//     args: ["world", "kiwi"];
// }
const a = tag`hello ${'world'} ${'kiwi'}`;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCGBzGBeGAeAsAKBnmAogDYCmAtjCQB5QlgAmEM0ATgJZiIA0O%20MAKuQAOReLUo06jGACUS8euCIBPAIIsW8ZemLkAfD1z51yarQZNWHbr2MtETM1KYmA2gF0cegBS0yIsRIALgFhUVouGAA6GPh7CBDXGKiTCHcASlQ9GG8AbzgwwMi4hxgAX3ScHAB6aphQSFh4ENyaur4-ANoQwX9wkgBlKHZOCHVNZQBuNr4YEoSYVwAiAHcQFiJ6JcilgGs2FbYl92nsWvKcBug51DgkAAMACxIiIhAYABJcgHI1jfpvmVPj99odAfdTkA)

If you want to infer whole string, you either should use `${}` for each word or use regular function with infered string argument.
If you want to learn more about type inference on function arguments you can take a look at my [article](https://catchts.com/infer-arguments)

P.S. If you are interested in this feature, please like :thumb-up: above issue

Comment: That's too bad. What I need depends on the first parameter, so the function I'm trying to do is impossible. I was tried do implementing `...args` types depends on the first template string type.